# SaveStateHandle ViewModel: Save an Interface (Callback)

Tags: android, mvvm, viewmodel, android-viewmodel, savestate

Repository:

```
fun interface AllUsersQueryCallback{
fun getAllUsers(allUsers: LiveData<ArrayList<User>>)
}

private const val TAG = "SearchRepository"

class SearchRepository @Inject constructor(
val auth: FirebaseAuth,
val db: FirebaseDatabase,
val storage: FirebaseStorage
) {


fun fetchAllUsers(userID: String, callback: AllUsersQueryCallback) {
    var allUser: MutableLiveData<ArrayList<User>>
    val users: ArrayList<User> = ArrayList()


    val reference = db.reference.child(USERS).orderByChild("username")
    reference.addValueEventListener(object : ValueEventListener {
        override fun onDataChange(snapshot: DataSnapshot) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Query All Users: OnDataChange triggered")
            users.clear()
            for (singleUser in snapshot.children) {
                val user = singleUser.getValue(User::class.java)
                if (user!!.userID != userID) {
                    users.add(user)
                }

            }
            allUser = MutableLiveData(users)
            callback.getAllUsers(allUser)


        }

        override fun onCancelled(error: DatabaseError) {
            TODO("Not yet implemented")
        }

    })


}


}
```

**My Viewmodel:**

```
class SearchViewModel @ViewModelInject constructor(private val repository: SearchRepository, 
@Assisted val savedStateHandle: SavedStateHandle): ViewModel() {

//getting a list of all the users
fun fetchAllUsers(userID: String, callback: AllUsersQueryCallback) {
    
    savedStateHandle.set("user",userID)

    repository.fetchAllUsers(savedStateHandle.get("user")!!,callback)
}
}
```

Fragment:

```
    searchViewModel.fetchAllUsers(auth.currentUser!!.uid) {
        Log.d(TAG, "All users search data changed. Callback initiated")
      
        if(getView()!=null){
           it.observe(viewLifecycleOwner) { allUsers ->                   

               adapter.submitAllUserList(allUsers.toList())
               

           }
        }
    }
```

The view model calls the repository which queries the Firebase database to fetch all users. Since I cannot return the live data list of users, as the database query is asynchronous, I passed a callback
that updates the recycler view list once that query is completed.

Everything works fine. But upon process death I don't know how to save the callback. I can only save the userID string. Is it even possible to save callbacks/interfaces in SavedStateHandle? Please help me out.

Answer (score 0):

In `mvvm` architecture pattern your `viewModel` should not know about the `view`, this mean that you should have any interfaces to communicate with `view`. `View` should be subscribed/listen to any changes that happens in `viewModel` and react on them.

According to your question there is no way to save your callback. He connected to the fragment and will be destroyed with him.